# Golang time - time zone showing twice

Tags: go, time

On running this code the result should show date time and zone

Surprisingly the result shows time zone twice and am not able to figure out why

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    mytime, _ := time.Parse("02/Jan/2006:15:04:05 -0700", "07/Apr/2017:01:26:05 +0530")

    fmt.Println(mytime)

}
```

Output of this is

```
2017-04-07 01:26:05 +0530 +0530
```

So my question is why timezone showing twice ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `fmt.Println` invokes the `Time`'s `.String()` function that returns the time in the following format:

```
"2006-01-02 15:04:05.999999999 -0700 MST"
```

Which as you see contains both the timezone offset and the timezone name.

In your case there is no timezone name known for the time, so it outputs the offset twice.

References:

- https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.String

Comment: Wow! Am so impressed

Comment: Weird, we're seeing +0000 +0000 and clearly UTC should be known.  Any thoughts why UTC is not displayed?

Comment: @bitrock without seeing your code it's hard to tell