# Parsing a UTC ISO8601 time format in Golang

Tags: go

I'm being sent a date in the following format:

```
2021-05-09T12:10:00+01:00
```

Which is apparently a valid date format: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

I'm attempting to parse that date in Go:

```
pt, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04:05+00:00", dt)
```

I've also tried to use `time.RFC3339`

But neither seem to pick up the timezone. In this case I get:

```
2021/05/10 21:02:02 http: panic serving [::1]:62125: parsing time "2021-05-09T12:10:00 01:00" as "2006-01-02T15:04:05+00:00": cannot parse " 01:00" as "+00:00"
```

Comment: Your date string contains a space character instead of a plus, most likely because it wasn't percent encoded for use in a query string.

Comment: You know what, that's exactly it! Great spot! Thanks!

If you post as a reply I'll select as the answer

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your `layout` parameter,
`"2006-01-02T15:04:05+00:00"`
Instead of `+00:00` you should have `-07:00`

This should help,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    date := "2021-05-09T12:10:00+01:00"
    layout := "2006-01-02T15:04:05-07:00"
    t, err := time.Parse(layout, date)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(t)
}
```

Output: 2021-05-09 12:10:00 +0100 +0100
Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/UcrIDfJRcNV

Don't get confused as to why the timezone is showing up twice.
It's explained in this answer,
[Golang time - time zone showing twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43264783/golang-time-time-zone-showing-twice)

The special `layout` parameter only accepts a certain set of valid numbers.
You can refer them here,
https://yourbasic.org/golang/format-parse-string-time-date-example/

Comment: Thanks, great example. It turned out that the + was being stripped out of the URL, so was invalid by the time I was calling parse on it as well

Answer (score 1):

You need to relay the timezone via the number `-7:00` (not `+1:00`):

```
// pt, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04:05+1:00", dt) // not this

pt, err :=    time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04:05-07:00", dt) // this
```

https://play.golang.org/p/n697vKUHSjD

Comment: Thanks, great example! Turns out the plus/minus was being stripped out by the url encoding as well